# What you cannot do List<W> l1 = new ArrayList<String>(); while this works when calling method

Tags: java, generics

I am really not able to understand that why I get compilation error when in first case while works fine in second case.

```
public class GenericsTest3 {

    public static <W> void main(String[] args) {
        List<W> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();       // compilation error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to List<W>
        doSomething1(new ArrayList<String>());      // works fine
    }
    
    public static <L> L doSomething1(List<L> list) {
        list.get(0);
        list.add(list.get(0));
        return list.get(1);
    }
    
}
```

In my understand in both the cases List is defined of type parameter T/W, so why parameterized type `new ArrayList<String>()` fails in one case while passes in other case.

Comment: How do you know `W` is `String`?

Comment: Why are you even doing `List<W>` instead of `List<String>` there?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<W> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Issue here is, that you declare a variable l1 for a List of type W items, but then you assign an (Array)List of type String to it. This is only acceptable, if W is also String.

You can just use W as type argument for the ArrayList or remove type argument from it.

```
List<W> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Regarding your next question:

```
doSomething1(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Here you simply create a new ArrayList of type String and pass it as argument to doSomething1. At doSomething1, type argument L will therefore be String.

Answer (score 1):

**case 1 :**

```
List<W> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You are telling java that create a generic list and in the same declaration you are specifying the data type as String. So compiler is confused what to do.

**Case 2 :**

```
<L> L doSomething1(List<L> list) method
```

In this case java knows that generic list is input . All the action done on List interface. So compiles.

Answer (score 0):

A generic method (i.e. a method with type parameters declared specifically for that method, like you have here) means that the method can be called with the generic type parameter being any type within that type parameter's bounds, and you guarantee that the method will work. So a caller can call your `main` method, and explicitly choose `W` to be a specific type of their choosing, and you guarantee that your method will work with `W` being that type, without even knowing what `W` is. Here, that is clearly not true, since, if `W` is chosen to be anything other than `String`, the line `List<W> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();` is invalid.

The same thing is true for the `doSomething1` method -- you guarantee that no matter what type then caller chooses for `L`, the method will work. And here, it is true. The lines inside the `doSomething1` method will work no matter what you substitute for `L`.

When you call the `doSomething1` method from `main`, you are the caller, so you can choose for its `L` type parameter to be whatever type you want. You choose for `L` to be `String` (or the compiler infers this choice for you). That is perfectly fine.